# QT Text to speech module

Tags: qt

I got a problem with QT creator. I wanted to compile the QGroundcontrol code and than I got a error message: **-1: error: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: texttospeech location-private positioning-private charts x11extras waylandclient**
I've installed every QT Version above 5 and also version 6. I've looked at many pages and didn't find a solution.

My OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

thank you for helping me out!

Comment: you managed to fix also waylandclient ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add QT += texttospeech to the project file as well as install the QTexttospeech module

Comment: do you know which module I need to install to fix the same problem with waylandclient ?